# print sum of strings as float

Tags: python, string, decimal, floating-point-conversion

I am working on an exercise that states:

> Let `s` be a string that contains a sequence of decimal numbers
>   separated by commas, e.g., `s = '1.23,2.4,3.123'`.  Write a program that
>   prints the sum of the numbers in `s`.

My solution is:

```
s = '1.23,2.4,3.123'
news = s + ","
value = ""
floatValue = 0


for i in range(len(news)):
    if news[i] != ',':
        value += s[i]
    elif news[i] == ',':
        floatValue += float(value)
        value = ""

print floatValue
```

I was just wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this? Also I'm in the beginning of a Python course so at this point I am only trying to accomplish this with a beginner-level solution.

Comment: I think he still can't upvote because although all of his answerers thought his question was good enough to answer, they didn't think it was good enough to upvote. Well, there's one from me now...

Comment: Thanks. I was getting an error when I first tried to upvote cause I didn't have enough points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, significantly:

```
>>> s = '1.23,2.4,3.123'
>>> sum(map(float, s.split(",")))
6.753
```

This uses [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to divide the string up into numbers:

```
>>> s.split(",")
['1.23', '2.4', '3.123']
```

[`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) to apply [`float`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#float) to each string

```
>>> map(float, s.split(","))
[1.23, 2.4, 3.123]
```

and [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) to add up the total.

---

As there are several answers with slightly different approaches, I thought I'd test them out to see which was most efficient:

**2.7.6**

```
>>> import timeit
>>> def f1(s):
    return sum(map(float, s.split(",")))

>>> def f2(s):
    return sum(float(x) for x in s.split(","))

>>> def f3(s):
    return sum([float(x) for x in s.split(",")])

>>> timeit.timeit("f1(s)", setup="from __main__ import f1, f2, f3;s='1.23,2.4,3.123'")
2.627161979675293
>>> timeit.timeit("f2(s)", setup="from __main__ import f1, f2, f3;s='1.23,2.4,3.123'")
2.805773973464966
>>> timeit.timeit("f3(s)", setup="from __main__ import f1, f2, f3;s='1.23,2.4,3.123'")
2.6547701358795166
```

**3.4.0**

```
>>> timeit.timeit("f1(s)", setup="from __main__ import f1, f2, f3;s='1.23,2.4,3.123'")
2.3012791969995305
>>> timeit.timeit("f2(s)", setup="from __main__ import f1, f2, f3;s='1.23,2.4,3.123'")
3.1761953750028624
>>> timeit.timeit("f3(s)", setup="from __main__ import f1, f2, f3;s='1.23,2.4,3.123'")
3.1163038839986257
```

---

Bonus round for Ashwini (**3.4.0**):

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> def f4(s):
    return sum(literal_eval(s))

>>> timeit.timeit("f4(s)", setup="from __main__ import f1, f2, f3, f4;s='1.23,2.4,3.123'")
23.054055102998973
>>> timeit.timeit("f1(s)", setup="from __main__ import f1, f2, f3, f4;s='1.23,2.4,3.123'")
2.2302689969983476
```

This works (slowly!) using [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to interpret the string as a tuple of floats:

```
>>> literal_eval('1.23,2.4,3.123')
(1.23, 2.4, 3.123)
```

Comment: Also try with `sum(literal_eval(s))`, it might be the fastest one of the lot.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I make it slower by a factor of 10!

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for the results, my speculation was wrong.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I guess because `literal_eval` has to put some work into determining what data structure it's evaluating, whereas the other versions already "know".

Answer (score 1):

```
s = '1.23,2.4,3.123'
```

Short and sweet:

```
print sum(map(float, s.split(',')))
```

Beginner level:

```
total = 0
for f in s.split(','):
    total += float(f)
print total
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s = '1.23,2.4,3.123'
```

Use a generator expression to avoid unnecessarily materializing a list in both Python 2 and 3. This usage has generally supplanted `map` due to its improved readability:

```
sum(float(n) for n in s.split(','))
```

returns

```
6.7530000000000001
```

In Python 3, map returns an iterator, so it has approximately the same performance:

```
sum(map(float, s.split(',')))
```

But in Python 2, it will unnecessarily create a list as an intermediate step.

Style guides prefer generator expressions and list comprehensions to `map` and `filter`, see [Google's Python style guide](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html?showone=List_Comprehensions#List_Comprehensions) for example:

> List comprehensions and generator expressions provide a concise and efficient way to create lists and iterators without resorting to the use of map(), filter(), or lambda.

[They were created with the intention of reducing the need for `map` and `filter`.](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/)

Comment: `timeit` suggests that your first version is, if anything, slightly slower (2.55s vs 2.38s for `map`, v2.7.6)

Comment: Interestingly, it also suggests that explicitly creating the list then passing it to `sum` is faster than passing the generator - the former is on a par with `map`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe most style guides conclude that readability trumps performance.

Comment: That's a fair trade, but I'm not convinced that a generator expression is more or less readable than `map`.

Comment: I would say that *"...created with the intention of reducing the need..."* is reading beyond the text. What the PEP actually says is *"...expected to minimize the need..."*. The rationale was to conserve memory where the full list (comprehension) isn't needed. And the Google link is downright misleading - they are clear [later in the guide](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html?showone=Deprecated_Language_Features#Deprecated_Language_Features) that use of `map` where the `func` argument *isn't a `lambda`* is acceptable.

Comment: They reduce/minimize the need for both, and the imap/ifilter became map/filter in Python 3. Acceptable isn't the same as preferable. Most people, especially those new to functional programming, find map and filter quite difficult to understand, whereas list comps and generator expressions are quite readily understood.

Comment: Yes, they reduce it, but that is not the same as your claim *"created with the intention of reducing"*. No, acceptable is not the same as preferable, but the style guide you linked to does not refer to *either* as preferable (although the use of the word *"resort"* implies a dispreference for `map`). And plenty of new Python users seem confused by generator expressions (although I also think that they are readily understood).

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) for split the string with `,` then convert any index to float !

```
>>> sum([float(i) for i in s.split(',')])
6.753
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done this way:

```
s = '1.23,2.4,3.123'
val = sum([float(x) for x in s.split(',')])
```

Answer (score 0):

The Begginer level solution in my opinion without adding comma at the end of the string:

```
s = '1.23,2.4,3.123'
num=''
sum=0
for i in s:
    if i != ',':
        num+=i
    else:
        sum+=float(num)
        num=''
sum+=float(num) # To add last number which was left out due to no comma.
print(sum)
```